# Setting an object to a split array

Tags: javascript

I'm not a javascript guru.  I've got the following code below:

```
var aCookieValues = sCookieContentString.split('&'); // split out each set of key/value pairs
var aCookieNameValuePairs = aCookieValues.split('='); // return an array of each key/value
```

What  I'm trying to do is split the first string via & and then create another array that takes the first array and splits it further via the = character that exists in every value in the aCookieValues array

I get the error aCookieValues.split is not a function.

I've seen an example that basically does the same thing but the second time this guy is using a loop:

(http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/01/16/javascript-query-string/)

```
    // '&' seperates key/value pairs
    var pairs = querystring.split("&");

    // Load the key/values of the return collection  
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var keyValuePair = pairs[i].split("=");
        queryStringDictionary[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1];
    }
```

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve here is a final dictionary with key/value pairs based off the '=' split.  I'm simply trying to split up a cookie's values and shove it into a nice dictionary so I can then get certain values out of that dictionary later on.

Comment: Why don’t you use the algorithm you already have?

Comment: what algorithm.  You talking about the 2nd example?  that's from that guy's blog.  And honestly I don't fully understand a couple things he's doing such as = {}; and how he's creating a dictionary in JavaScript..there aren't dictionaries in JavaScript are there?

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Everything is a dictionary in JavaScript :)

Comment: ... See the "Objects" section here: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html

Comment: So you’re rather asking for an explanation of that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because `aCookieValues` is an array, and it does not have a `split` method. You would need to call the `split` method on each element of `aCookieValues`:

```
var aCookieValues = sCookieContentString.split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < aCookieValues.length; i++) {
   var aCookieNameValuePairs = aCookieValues[i].split('=');

   // Handle aCookieNameValuePairs[0] as the key
   // Handle aCookieNameValuePairs[1] as the value
}
```

To shove everything in your nice dictionary, simply declare it before the for loop: `var myDict = {}`, and then put the following after the `split('=')` call:

```
myDict[aCookieNameValuePairs[0]] = aCookieNameValuePairs[1];
```

---

**EDIT:** Which, after reading your question properly, is the same method used in the code snippet you supplied. I hope at least this explains how that works :)

Comment: I'm just wondering how not to do this with a loop the second time.

Comment: this is the line I don't get.  myDict[aCookieNameValuePairs[0]] = aCookieNameValuePairs[1];  And I did not know there are JavaScript dictionaries after trying to look it up...there isn't looks like but I just found a nice article finally http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100800-1.shtml

Comment: You have to use a loop. Actually you could use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/map), but that's quite advanced, and is just a shorthand for looping through all the elements of the array. (And it does not work in all browsers).

Comment: @coffeeaddict: JavaScript dictionaries are really straightforward. Your declare one: `var myDict = {};`... Then you simply do `myDict['myKey'] = 'someValue';`... You can then call `alert(myDict['myKey'])` and you'd be alerted `someValue`... That part you quoted is basically doing the same thing, since `aCookieNameValuePairs[0]` is just a string with the key of each element of `aCookieValues`, and `aCookieNameValuePairs[1]` is the value.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: I suggest checking out  the section "Objects" at: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html... Note that ` = new Object()` and ` = {}` are the same thing. The latter is just a shorthand notation, called the "object literal".

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Will check that out now.  I'm just used to static languages...so this is a bit of a pain for me.

Comment: coffeeaddict: Don't worry. Once you get used to them, I bet you won't go back to static languages :)

Comment: Danial, ok so that article says:  var myHashtable = {};

This statement makes a new hashtable and assigns it to a new local variable   but you are saying that {} just creates an object right?  There is no concept of a hashtable object or is there?

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Continue reading a bit more until you reach the part that says: **"JavaScript takes this much farther: objects and hashtables are the same thing"** :) ... That's why I said in another comment to your question that "Everything is a dictionary in JavaScript". Because everything is an object, and objects are just hashtables :) It may sound funny, but that turns out to be very useful!

Comment: ... BTW, you may want to install Firebug in Firefox or use the JavaScript Console in Chrome to try these out in a JavaScript REPL shell.

Comment: I've got firebug and have been using it for years.  and I do use the javascript console which is how I see this error.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this helped a lot, did not find links as good as you showed here yet when researching on the net.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: That's great! :)

Comment: @coffeeaddict: If you like video lectures, and you have a couple of hours to spare, I suggest checking out the first four at: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/learning-javascript-programming-language-through-video-lectures. They're really good at introducing concepts such as these. They are given by Douglas Crockford, which is very authoritative in the subject (the same author of the link I provided).

Comment: Thanks much!!  Appreciate all the advice here.

Answer (score 1):

`split` operates on a string. You're trying to split `aCookieValues`, which is an array. The example you cite is looping through the array, and then splitting each element as a string.

Just for fun, one way to deal with this would be to use a `map` function, which performs an action on each element of an array, and emits an array as a result. If you make a generic map function available to all your arrays, like this:

```
if (!Array.prototype.map) { // don't step on anyone's toes
  Array.prototype.map = function( f ) {
    var result = [];
    var aLen = this.length;
    for( x = 0 ; x < aLen ; x++ ) {
      result.push( f(this[x]) );
    }
    return result; 
  };
};
```

...you can call it as a method on your array directly. Thus:

```
​yourstring = 'x=3&y=4&zed=blah&something=nothing';
dictionary = yourstring.split('&').map( function(a){ return a.split('='); } );
```

`dictionary` will now be a nice clean array of (arrays of) name/value pairs, like this:

```
[["x", "3"], ["y", "4"], ["zed", "blahblah"], ["something", "nothing"]]
```

If your use case becomes complex, an approach like this can be a nice abstraction. Of course, you can arrange these data in other structures if needed, either by playing with a function passed into map, or processing in a separate pass.

Comment: thanks, I'm not that advanced in JS yet..did not know of maps.

Comment: I don't understand how the passed in function with the x param works..is that basically some kind of delegate?

Comment: The map function above is defined as taking argument `f`. In the body of `map`, we see that the `f` argument is a function, which is called inside the `for` loop -- `f(this[x])`. The argument passed in is `this[x]` -- meaning, the current element of the original array in question. Think of the `function(a)` code (I changed it to `a` for clarity) as a sort of template -- a general form of the function we want to pass to `map`. When the function is actually applied inside `map`, we're just saying "take the actual argument, and slot it in wherever we had `a` in that "template".

Comment: I don't think map() is (yet?) standard. You can't rely on its presence or uniform behavior across implementations of js. I'm defining a basic version here, but it would probably be smart to check for it first. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: cool I will definitely look into that moving forward as a valuable approach.  I need to digest it first.

Answer (score 1):

In your second line you are attempting to call split() on an array, when it is a function defined on strings.

Example:

```
"a=1&b=2&c=3".split('&') returns an array ['a=1','b=2','c=3']
```

Your code would then call split on the array:

```
['a=1','b=2','c=3'].split('=')
```

But that function doesn't exist.  It seems like your goal is to split each string in the array, so the example you gave in the question seems appropriate - loop through each element and split it.